# How to properly dockerize dev and prod environment with nextjs 13 app directory

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose

I have my dev.Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i; \
  # Allow install without lockfile, so example works even without Node.js installed locally
  else echo "Warning: Lockfile not found. It is recommended to commit lockfiles to version control." && yarn install; \
  fi

COPY . .


# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage. Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line to disable telemetry at run time
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

# Note: Don't expose ports here, Compose will handle that for us

# Start Next.js in development mode based on the preferred package manager
CMD \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn dev; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run dev; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then pnpm dev; \
  else yarn dev; \
  fi
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  docker-prod:
    container_name: docker-prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

running the command docker-compose up gives me the error

```
docker-prod  | Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
docker-prod  |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
docker-prod  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
docker-prod  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
docker-prod  |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
docker-prod  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
docker-prod  |   requireStack: []
docker-prod  | }
```

I tried changing different paths and the COPY command. What could be possibly wrong in my dockerfile?

Comment: Your `volumes:` mount is hiding literally everything the Dockerfile does.  I'd recommend deleting it.  You don't need the conditional in the Dockerfile either; you should know which packaging system your application uses, so just `RUN yarn install` or `RUN npm ci` as appropriate.  I'd recommend just using plain Node for day-to-day development (installing Node is probably easier than installing Docker).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for hours (nextjs + pnpm is my first Docker project so I was pretty lost lol)

Turns out the abover message is caused by NOT HAVING a `.dockerignore` file ([see this link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/.dockerignore)) in your project.

Contents of this file in case link breaks:

```
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
node_modules
npm-debug.log
README.md
.next
.git
```

Edit: The relevant entry is `node_modules`!